# Is there any language that $\bar L^*= (\bar L)^*$?

Tags: automata, formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

Can we answer to this question or no, this is unknown?

> Is there any language that $\bar L^*= (\bar L)^*$?

Comment: Could you mention the name of the operation $L\mapsto\bar L$ for those of us less familiar with the field? I assume ${}^*$ is the Kleene star, which is at least on the wikipedia page so a bit easier to find (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language)

Comment: @stewbasic this is complement operation, and for * you are correct, this is Kleen star.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we denote the empty string by $\epsilon$, then by definition $\epsilon\in A^*$ for any language $A$. Consequently, $\epsilon\notin\overline{(L^*)}$ and $\epsilon\in\left(\overline{L}\right)^*$ so the left and right sides of your equation can never be equal.